# Yii 2: Using a class from inside a require_once

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using a 3rd party extension like so:

(This is inside my controller)

```
require_once Yii::$app->basePath.'/vendor/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/csrest_subscribers.php';

$wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers($list_id, $auth);
```

However, this is returning an error that CS_REST_subscribers class is not found.

How do I use this class correctly when the class is inside the file. Unfortunately this extension is older and is not namespaced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it using composer with the following command

```
composer require  "campaignmonitor/createsend-php" "6.0.0"
```

It uses the simplest way, i.e autoloads each class separately. we define the array of paths to the classes that we want to autoload in the `composer.json` file and if you see the `vendor/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/composer.json` file inside the package directory

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "csrest_administrators.php",
        "csrest_campaigns.php",
        "csrest_clients.php",
        "csrest_general.php",
        "csrest_events.php",
        "csrest_lists.php",
        "csrest_people.php",
        "csrest_segments.php",
        "csrest_subscribers.php",
        "csrest_templates.php",
        "csrest_transactional_classicemail.php",
        "csrest_transactional_smartemail.php",
        "csrest_transactional_timeline.php"

    ]
}
```

so you won't need the `include` or `require` statement, you can directly call any class you want for instance adding the following lines inside your `action` or `view`

```
$authorize_url = CS_REST_General::authorize_url(
    '1122',//'Client ID for your application',
    'http://example.com/redirect-page',//Redirect URI for your application,
    'ViewReports'//The permission level your application requires,
);
print_r($authorize_url);
```

prints the following

https://api.createsend.com/oauth?client_id=1122&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fredirect-page&scope=ViewReports

For knowledge base if you want to use a Third-party code that is not using autoloader or psr4 you can go through the [Yii tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-integration)